# Understanding C++ operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

I was reading the source of a hashing competition today, and came across this:

```
#define BYTES_IN_BLOCK 1024

struct block{
    uint8_t v[BYTES_IN_BLOCK];

    block(){ memset(v, 0, BYTES_IN_BLOCK); }
    uint64_t& operator[](uint8_t i){ return *(uint64_t*)(v + 8 * i); }
};
```

Then, a little later in the code, there's this:

```
state = new block[cost]; // cost is a uint32_t (like 1024)
// Probably 50 lines of code.
block prev_block;

prev_block = state[foo]; // foo is a uint32_t
```

What I can't figure out is what this is doing. Now, I understand C, but C++ not so much. Bear with me here for a second.

This part: `return *(uint64_t*)(v+8*i)` should return a `uint64_t`, and does so when I tested it:

```
state->v[8*10] = 12;
uint64_t bar = *(uint64_t*)(v+8*10);
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", bar);
```

So that all makes sense.

But this:

`prev_block = state[foo];`

Makes no sense. Since `state` is `block*`, `prev_block` should now "be" `state`, correct? But it doesn't, because their arrays are different.

```
state->v[8*12] = 12;
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", (*state)[12]);
prev_block = state[12];
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", (*(&prev_block))[12]);
```

So, what exactly is going on here?

Comment: state is "block*" but prev_block is correctly "block" since it is defined as "state[foo]" which is " *(state + foo) ".

Comment: Ugh. This code is waay too clever. `struct block` should just be `std::array< std::uint64_t, BYTES_IN_BLOCK / sizeof (std::uint64_t) >`. The way it's written, `block prev_block` might be misaligned in memory.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but this entire concept violates the [strict aliasing rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). (so all of the code has undefined behaviour)

Comment: @Potatoswatter `std::aligned_storage` is probably more appropriate

Comment: For the record, this isn't my code. It's from a recent hash algorithm contest. This is (scarily) part of the winning code. @MattMcNabb Thanks for that link -- it was a good read and a good reminder.

Comment: @Potatoswatter You should see the rest of their code >:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up the two `operator[]`s involved here.  In your last example, you set `state[0][12] = 12`, and you're comparing it to `state[12][12]`.  Since `state` is a `block*`, `state[n]` is just normal array access; it doesn't invoke the `operator[]` defined in `block`.

Comment: And now after that explanation I feel ridiculously stupid for not catching that. Definitely not one of my brightest moments. Thanks, Miles.

Comment: @eric_lagergren this is your answer, but there are a few other things going on in that code and your print test at the bottom you need to know about before they bite you.

Answer (score 1):

```
state = new block[cost];
prev_block = state[foo];
```

is analogous to:

```
int* arr = new int[size];
int a = arr[index];
```

That's basic C++. I am not sure why that is confusing.

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't recall mentioning I had a grasp on C++. That last bit was unwarranted.

Comment: @eric_lagergren, I didn't mean anything offensive. I was just puzzled.

Comment: It's alright. If you're wondering, it was a dead simple question. The operator overloading happened to confuse me and cause me to overlook the simple array index bit. Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 1):

There is confusion with a number of concepts here. I'm going to blast through all the ones I see because they are all important, not just the immediate answer.

`state` is a pointer to block, but `state[0]` should just be a block, specifically the first block in state and also the result of `*state`.

```
prev_block = state[foo];
```

All of the data in block is simple, just a self-contained array of bytes, so it should be directly copy-able without any special assistance. `prev_block = state[foo]` should copy state[foo] to prev_block. Since it's a copy, the addressing will be different.

In the printout code provided:

```
state->v[8*12] = 12;
```

Breaking his down for clarity. `state->` is going to access the first element of the state array. `state->v[8*12]` is going to access v[8*12] of state[0]. `state->v[8*12] = 12;` is going to set v[8*12] of state[0]to 12. This means byte 96 of v is going to be 12. To reference a different state you can use `(state + array_index)->v[8*12];` or `state[array_index].v[8*12];` I find the latter more readable.

```
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", (*state)[12]);
```

`(*state)` gives you the first state in the array, AKA `state[0]`. `(*state)[12]` uses `state[0]`'s [] operator, defined as `uint64_t& operator[](uint8_t i){ return *(uint64_t*)(v + 8 * i); }`

This is going to return a 64 bit int starting at the address of state[0].v[12*8] and comprised of the next 8 bytes of array v (v[96] through v[103], resulting in 12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0). This will be 12 or a god-awful big number depending on the system's [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). The wrapping printf is going to print the returned number.

```
prev_block = state[12];
```

Is going to copy the 13th element of the state array to prev_block, assuming enough blocks were created by `state = new block[cost];`. Nothing magical, but there shouldn't be anything there but zeros because the only state that has any values set is state[0]. You either wanted to copy `state[0]` here or write to `state[12]` up a few lines.

```
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", (*(&prev_block))[12]);
```

the * and & cancel each other out before accomplishing anything. It will then print out the result of using the block [] operator as above. Should be zero.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for this write up. Most of this I already understand, e.g., array indexes, pointers. The bit at the end was to shush the compiler from complaining about using an operator without a pointer.

Anyway, thanks again. After Miles' answer I noticed I was making a stupid mistake that I _should_ have caught but didn't because the operator overloading was tripping me up. Great answer though.

Comment: And for the record, other than my little test snippets, this isn't my C++. It's from a (Google's?) recent hash algorithm contest. This is part of the winning code.

Comment: @eric_lagergren You might want make that point in your question. The code is already being dissected unfavourably.

Comment: Ehhh, I kind of like seeing the code get picked apart... I don't write C++ (only some C when needed) so it's been an interesting SO thread :-)